# Como alterar o window.location de um frame

Tags: javascript, html

Queria saber se é possível inserir um target aqui:

```
window.location='www.google.com';
```

Não quero para abrir em uma nova página, senão usaria `window.open`. Quero usar um `target="topFrame"` para controlar um player.

Estou utilizando uma coisinha antiga (frameset). Estou utilizando assim no link `<a href="system/radio/on.php" target="topFrame">`.

Comment: Se esta usando um `Frame`, ja tentou usar o atributo `src` do mesmo? Você também pode manipular o `Frame` usando a API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames.

Comment: Você pode alterar o `location` do `Frame` (se for do mesmo domínio) usando o objeto DOM do `Frame`. Se não terá que usar o atributo `src` dele.

Comment: Obrigado, por oque você falou aqui eu dei uma pesquisada em cima de umas dicas suas e encontrei http://javascript.about.com/library/bltarget.htm

Comment: @Wakim Não quer postar uma resposta explicando melhor isso? Para mim é a resposta correta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom, esta aqui a solução que encontrei.

Como estava utilizando

```
<a href="system/radio/on.php" target="topFrame"> <div class="icone_som_um"> </a>
```

Como estou utilizando agora

```
function tocar() {
    top.frames['topFrame'].location.href = 'system/radio/on.php';
}
```

Estou acionando a função em js assim

```
<div class="icone_som_um" onClick="tocar()">
```

Comment: Sei como você esta utilizando esse frameset, muitas web rádios utilizam, esse tópico vai ser muito útil.